# Detect if 2 Controls(Shapes) Overlap in a Grid Control (Windows Phone 8)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to build a game in Windows Phone 8. A car race kind of Game, in which I have a car (assume a rectangle). I have an obstacle (assume a circle) moving towards it. Unless the car moves away, the obstacle should hit the car. How do i detect when the car and the obstacle in the same place?

Comment: _How do i detect when the car and the obstacle in the same place?_ By writing code...

Comment: You need to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection

Comment: @Eminem: I know it is via code. :P

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm